# Select text in input text field on click in angular2 in IE11

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a text input. When the input receives focus I want to select the text inside of the input.
I have written below code in Angular2 and it works perfectly in Google Chrome but does not work in IE11.

```
<input type="text" name="Description" id="Description" [(ngModel)]="Description" maxlength="20" (click)="$event.target.select()">
```

I have tried on  (mouseup)="$event.target.select()" too. It also works in chrome but not in IE11.
I've searched around to try and find the Angular2 way.There is away to do this in Angularjs using directive. Can i achieve the same in Angular2 also which works in Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try using (focus)?

Comment: Do you want something like this?:https://plnkr.co/edit/ia9dv530yxfnqaDHikaq?p=preview

Comment: @Salander: i have tried with Focus

Comment: @Aakash: When i clicked on input box Text should get selected

Comment: It is getting selected. Did you see the plunker? I might be missing something here. Can you please elaborate a little.

Comment: Yes Aakash i have checked the Plunker.My requirement is when i click on my input box or sets a focus . The text inside the input box should get selected. For eg. In plunker "Angular" text should get selected when i click inside the input box.. I hope , i am able to clear the requirement. Thank you.

Comment: I used Akash's plunker to try it with focus, it's working fine for me.

Comment: Check https://plnkr.co/edit/PuhJKwqkqvO56VzXVXVH?p=preview

Comment: Hi Salander, I have used the approach you have given in the above plunker url. It worked for me on focus. Since, I had some validation on the input box on Focus event and it was not allowing me to select . I have added the event.target.select() after all my validation were fired. Thank you for helping me out in this.

Comment: Anytime, I'll add this as an answer. Please accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the (focus) event provided by angular2 as demonstarted in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PuhJKwqkqvO56VzXVXVH?p=preview)

```
<input type="text" name="Description" placeholder={{description}} [(ngModel)]="description" maxlength="20" (focus)="$event.target.select()">
  <div *ngIf="selectedValue">{{selectedValue}}</div>
```